# Easily sync CoreData and CloudKit

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I have an app where I have enabled CloudKit and it works great for syncing across multiple devices.

However where it doesn't work is syncing for a widget, where I've read the optimal approach is to use CoreData and then separately sync to CloudKit.

Have I understood it correctly that CloudKit doesn't work to sync to widgets?

If so, is there an easy approach to syncing existing CoreData to CloudKit? Most approaches seem pretty convoluted.